# STAThread missing, but it is there

Tags: c#

Here is the error message that I am recieving when I try to open an OpenFileDialog in my program:

> "Current thread must be set to single
>   thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE
>   calls can be made. Ensure that your
>   Main function has STAThreadAttribute
>   marked on it. This exception is only
>   raised if a debugger is attached to
>   the process."

The problem with this error message is that my Main method DOES have the STAThread attribute attached to it.  I am at a loss as to how to handle this.  How can I add something if it is already there.  Doubling it up is not a good option, and I tried erasing it, building the app, adding it and building it again with no success.  I just don't understand.

```
private void btnOldFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
     openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
     openFileDialog1.ShowHelp = false;
     openFileDialog1.AutoUpgradeEnabled = true;
     openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
     openFileDialog1.Filter = "Microsoft Installer (*.msi)|*.msi|All Files (*.*)|*.* ";
     openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
     openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

     if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         textBoxOldInstallation.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
     }
}
```

and the main method is:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

And no threading is done explicitly.  Just a pretty basic program to be honest.

EDIT2::

Here is the complete error message including call stack

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException was unhandled
>     Message="Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."
>     Source="System.Windows.Forms"
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()
>          at MSI_Comparison_GUI.Form1.btnOldFind_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\tfs\DocuWare .NET\DocuWare NewGen\src\Tools\MSI_Comparison\MSI_Comparison_GUI\Form1.cs:line 70
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at MSI_Comparison_GUI.Program.Main() in c:\tfs\DocuWare .NET\DocuWare NewGen\src\Tools\MSI_Comparison\MSI_Comparison_GUI\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException:

Comment: Can you show us the code, how you create the dialog? And did you create another thread in your program?

Comment: has been added for your reading pleasure :P

Comment: Are you sure that you are executing in the main thread at that point and that openFileDialog1 has been created in the main thread?

Comment: I added the openFileDialog1 onto the form in the designer, then I used the code listed above in form1.cs.  It is the same as I have done millions of times before. Maybe not millions, but you know what I mean.

Comment: Maybe your project has more than one `Main` method and another one than you think is used? The one used here is `MSI_Comparison_GUI.Program.Main()` in in c:\tfs\DocuWare .NET\DocuWare NewGen\src\Tools\MSI_Comparison\MSI_Comparison_GUI\Program.cs:line 18.

Comment: Can you post the code for the method `btnOldFind_Click`?  Starting from the method signature until `openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;`

Comment: @0xA3 after a search I have only found the one main method.  And the one that you pointed to in your comment is the one shown above with the STAThread attribute listed.

@Will The only thing missing from the method is the signature : private void btnOldFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @Adkins if that's the case, the one last option you have is to attempt to repro this in another solution using the least amount of code as possible.  If you can, open a [Connect w/MS](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).  Post the addy here and I'll upvote it.  If you CANNOT repro, you have to comb through both projects, line by line, partial class by partial class, project file by project file and see what is different between the two.  Sorry I can't offer more help than that.

Comment: A note for anyone else arriving here in 2021, but probably not the OPs problem: The STAThread attribute will also be ignored if your entry point is async (or at least async returning task). In that case even trying to explicitly set the threading model using SetApartmentState will fail. It appears if your main entry point is async then you must be MTA.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be that you are facing the following problem reported on Connect<sup>1</sup>:

> **[.vshost.exe forces wrong threading model used when debugging a .exe if a .dll of the same name exists in same bin directory](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/108261/vshost-exe-forces-wrong-threading-model-used-when-debugging-a-exe-if-a-dll-of-the-same-name-exists-in-same-bin-directory)**

According to that issue it happens that the hosting process of Visual Studio, i.e. the myprogram.vshost.exe enforces the wrong apartment state when you have both a *myprogram.exe* and a *myprogram.dll* file in your output folder.

The problem might be specific to some older version of Visual Studio (2005), and I haven't been able to reproduce it using VS 2010.

The obvious workaround would be to change the name of the dll or to move the dll to another folder.

The situation might have come up because you changed the output type of your project from class libary to Windows application.

<sup>1</sup>It is unclear whether this problem is confirmed by Microsoft or not, it just says that the problem is outside the responsibility of the VS product team.

Comment: @Adkins: I'm just curious: Has this really been the problem? Are you on VS 2005 then?

Comment: Dangit, I was looking for something like that.  My fu failed.

Comment: @Hans Passant: As I cannot reproduce the problem it is hard to know the cause, personally I would suspect a bug in the vshost mechanism, but maybe it is related to the shell team at MS. Or to some lazy support engineer ;-)

Comment: Would be nice if we heard back from the OP.  I find the feedback report incredibly hard to believe.  That's just not how the hosting process works.

Comment: @Hans Passant:  This in fact was the culprit.  I had no external dlls, modules, toolkits, etc.  I stripped my program down so that it was all pure autogen VS code, plus my call to open the dialog and the problem persisted.  Once I changed the name of the exe (simply adding "_GUI" to it) the problem was gone.  I am still confused by it, but at least the problem is solved and gone!

Comment: @0xA3 thank you very much for your answer. Confirmed on VS2010 SP1.

Comment: Reproduced today in VS2013. I've restructured a solution and renamed some project, but two had the same assembly name, and one was a library project, so I indeed had a dll and a exe with the same name. Changing the DLL assembly name solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You've got an impossible stack trace.  It is clear that threading is not the cause of the problem, everything is running on the main thread and the [STAThread] attribute on your Main method is setting the apartment state.  The stack trace shows that it indeed the entrypoint.

Well, bad news, some kind of add-on is farking with your main thread.  Doing something nasty like calling CoUninitialize too many times.  I've had this happen to me once, took me a month to find it.  Start diagnosing this with Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick "Enable unmanaged code debugging".  That lets you see what DLLs are getting loaded into your program, it is shown in the Output window.

The first lead is when the dialog displays okay the *first* time but fails the *second* time.  Then you've got some kind of shell extension handler that wormed its way into your program.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility and disable any shell extension handler that wasn't made by Microsoft.

It gets harder when the dialog fails right away.  Then use Debug + Windows + Modules and go through the list of DLLs.  Pay attention to where they came from, shown in the Path column.  Distrust anything the doesn't quack like a .NET or Microsoft DLL.  Especially not having a Symbol File when you enabled the Microsoft Symbol Server is a lead.  A good way to make some headway with this is to compare that list to one you see on another machine that doesn't have this problem.

I do have a war-story about this.  My COM code was crashing on hundreds of machines, all I had to go by was a minidump.  Took me a month to discover the source, an open source project named ffdshow.  Very widely distributed, using different names as well.  It had a bug, calling CoUnitialize two times too many.  The bug was present in releases for two years but got fixed about a year and a half ago.  *Very* hard to diagnose, I didn't get close to it until I started looking at old releases.  If you do see ffdshow in your Modules window then you're close :)

Good luck, let us know the evil-doer.

Comment: "You've got an impossible stack trace". How do you mean "impossible"? The stack trace looks like a regular debugging stack trace to me...

Comment: @0xA3: impossible as in "that should not ever complain about the apartment state".

Answer (score 3):

Can't say without code.  If a console app, add the following before you call the method:

```
Console.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState);
```

otherwise,

```
MessageBox.Show(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState);
```

and see what the threading apartment state REALLY is.

Comment: It is a basic windows form application with no threading done on purpose.  I used that messagebox as suggested and it told me the state was MTA.  I really don't get how that can be cause like I said Main is marked with [STAThread] as done automatically by Visual Studio, and I don't do any other threading than a basic call to an OpenFileDialog.

Comment: @adkins are you sure you're not using a framework class that is masking multithreading?  Like the BackgroundWorker or using "BeginInvoke" on a delegate?  Multithreading doesn't just **happen** by accident.  Can you debug and let that exception get thrown again?  If you update your question with the call stack from the exception object I can probably tell you where the transition to MTA is happening, if you're using one of these framework classes that transition.

Comment: it is added, but it isnt pretty.  I don't use anything at all by the point this error is appearing. I am simply loading the program and clicking a button to open the OpenFileDialog.

Comment: @Adkins is there an inner exception?

Comment: no inner exception at all. What you see is what you get sadly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting breakpoints at the main procedure, the point where the dialogbox is created, and where it is used. Then look at what thread(s) you actually are in. Also, check what the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()` is at those points.

Comment: as stated above the current thread apartment state is MTA, but I am unsure why.

Comment: @Adkins: Is it MTA at all those locations, even directly in the main method?

Comment: @0xA3 I placed the check as the first statement in the main method and it was MTA.  It is seriously the STAThread attribute, the main signature, then the check.

Comment: Will you get the same result when you start the Debug version not from within VS but from Explorer or the command line? Place `MessageBox.Show(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState);` directly into your main method.

Comment: @0xA3 when I run it outside of VS but still the debug version it is STA and works fine.  Any chance you can shed some light on this for me.  I appreciate the answer, but I would like to better understand it if possible. Also if you place that in an answer I can mark it as answered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

The above line of code worked for me. once try it.