# FolderBrowseDialog STAThread error in background worker

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, folderbrowserdialog

Good day,

I'm getting an error very similar to the one discussed here (among other sources here and elsewhere): [STAThread missing, but it is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584434/stathread-missing-but-it-is-there)

The difference is that in my case I am using multi-threading. A `BackgroundWorker` is generating documents and when it's done, a `FolderBrowseDialog` will pop up to allow the user to choose a location to save the generated documents. So I can understand why I'm receiving this error. The reason I chose to put the `FolderBrowseDialog` in the `BackgroundWorker` events and related code is because then I have direct access to the path in stead of passing the string from one thread to the other.

Funny thing though, `PrintDialog` works but `SaveFileDialog` and `FolderBrowseDialog` throws this error.

I would just like to hear your thoughts. Would it be best to move the `FolderBrowseDialog` out of the `BackgroundWorker` code? Should I implement a custom `FolderBrowseDialog`? Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance for comments and advice and to everyone taking the time to consider my question; much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the FolderBrowseDialog being called in the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) callback or is it being called in the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) callback? If you're calling it from the DoWork callback, you'll need to use the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) the BackgroundWorker was created in and use the [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx) method to show the FolderBrowseDialog.

http://thedersen.com/2010/05/23/showing-modal-dialogs-from-a-background-thread/ is the closest example I can find on the web. In that example, the *Worker* class is used to store the SynchronizationContext.

Comment: Awesome, thanx! I used this approach and figured it out. Not sure if it was the best solution, but I started my `BackgroundWorker` with `Worker.RunWorkerAsync(SynchronizationContext.Current)` and then, in the `DoWork` event handler, I unbox the `DoWorkEventArgs` `Argument` object to a `SynchronizationContext` and use it to show the dialog. Is that how it's done? It works, but I don't know if it "good practice" or "standard convention" :)