# String copying to clipboard error

Tags: c#, runtime, clipboard

I am trying to read a file which include some commands that i want to be copied to clipboard. On searching internet i have found a way how to copy data into clipboard which i have done successfully. However i have to copy multiple commands. which i am doing in a while loop. Here is my code.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool CloseClipboard();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool SetClipboardData(uint uFormat, IntPtr data);

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\st4r8_000\Desktop\office work\checks documents\interface check commands.txt");
            OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero);
            //int x;
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (line);

                //clip board copier

                var yourString = line;
                var ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(yourString);
                SetClipboardData(13, ptr);

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                Console.ReadLine();
                //end of clip board copier
                counter++;
                //ptr = x;

            }
            CloseClipboard();
            file.Close();
            // Suspend the screen.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem i found is in the following line `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);`
or may be in `SetClipboardData(13, ptr);`but i do not know how to resolve this. This runs very fine in the first go but in second or third the program stop responding. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**I am not using windows forms. i am trying to build it in console.**

Comment: First of all why do you use user32.dll? There is a Clipboard class and SetText method (explained broadly in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Why not `Clipboard.SetText()`?

Comment: @DinosaurTom because i am not using windows forms. so i found out this as a solution.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko does `Clipboard.SetText()` works in console application ?

Comment: @Aqeel Abbas: Clipboard.SetText() should work with console applications as well; yes, `Clipboard` is in the `System.Windows.Forms` which is misleading.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko whenever i try to include `System.Windows.Forms` its say are you missing a assembly reference. I appreciate you help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't want all that *pInvoke* stuff, but `Clipboard.SetText`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms; // to have "Clipboard" class
using System.IO;            // to have "File" class

   ...
```

class Program
    {

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\st4r8_000\Desktop\office work\checks documents\error log check.txt");

        StringBuilder clipBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (String line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);

            if (clipBuffer.Length > 0)
                clipBuffer.Append('\n');

            clipBuffer.Append(line);
            Clipboard.SetText(line);
            // Incremental addition; 
            // Clipboard.SetText(line); 
            // if new line should superecede the old one
            //Clipboard.SetText(clipBuffer.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very new to c#. i am facing problem in `foreach` line. its says cant convert type char to string. please check this out [Errors](http://imgur.com/U4wJPyd)

Comment: @Aqeel Abbas: ensure that you have two using (see my edit), do not use `StreamReader` at all - see my code: `File.ReadLines(...)`; the last error is my fault (typo) `if (clipBuffer.Length > 0)`

Comment: I am creating console application. thats the reason i am using the dll thing. And i do not think so that in console application `System.Windows.Forms` can be used.

Comment: @Aqeel Abbas: why not? You can use any assemblies you want.

Comment: i got that. I am sorry as i am noob in it. I added a reference there and its okay now :)

Comment: one more little help if you can offer me. Please check this [error](http://imgur.com/3ngt8j3)

Comment: @Aqeel Abbas: looks like  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584434/stathread-missing-but-it-is-there does the application work alone? Outside Visual Studio?

Comment: Havent tried anywhere else as currently i am only using VS 2012

Comment: Ensure that `Main` is marked with `[STAThread]` attribute. `[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {...`

Comment: you are life saver :)